# Name of the concept of designing an interface to allow expert users to become more efficient?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I'm searching for sources and further information on a particular concept in user experience design. It's not a particularly complicated concept, just that when designing user interfaces, you should both make it intuitive and simple for new users, but also provide way for users to become more efficient as they become more familiar with the application.

An example could be including a prominent button for a common action for new users, but also providing a keyboard shortcut / mnemonic for expert users. However, that's just an example, another example could be providing full functionality through a GUI, but allow expert users to script the same actions. The point is it's more difficult to learn, but it makes them more efficient.

I'm pretty sure there's a name for that which I can't recall, and I'm having trouble searching for sources and references on it.

Name of the concept of designing an interface to allow expert users to become more efficient?

Comment: Accessibility? Ergonomy? Keyboard support?

Comment: None of those. It's a general, abstract term not specific to just keyboard shortcuts. My title question is probably a poor choice, I'll try to make that clearer.

Comment: I see. I'm eager to see what it is, when someone mentions it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question: **Efficiency.** It's a fundamental component of usability that [Jakob Nielsen long ago defined](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20030825.html) as "Once users have learned the design, how quickly can they perform tasks." A UI with expert-supporting elements like accelerators, context menus, and double-click-for-defaults is an efficient UI.

It is also correct to simply say that making things fast for experienced users is part of usability -just as usability also includes making it easy for users to accomplish basic tasks on the first encounter, and making it satisfying, and tolerating errors.

Comment: I think you're right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface#Terminology (though there is still a citation needed).

Answer (score 3):

Well, reading **only** your question "*Name of the concept of designing an interface to allow expert users to become more efficient?*" I'm inclined to point you toward [The Humane Interface: New Directions for Designing Interactive Systems](http://books.google.it/books?id=D39vjmLfO3kC) by Jef Raskin, in which there is the concept of [**habituation**](http://books.google.it/books?id=D39vjmLfO3kC&q=habituation#v=snippet&q=habituation&f=false):

> **2-3-1 Formation of Habits**
>
> When you perform a task repeatedly, it
>   tends to become easier to do.
>   Juggling, table tennis, and playing
>   piano are everyday examples in my
>   life; they all seemed impossible when
>   I first attempted them. Walking is a
>   more widely practiced example. With
>   repetition, or practice, your
>   competence becomes **habitual**, and you
>   can do the task without having to
>   think about it. ...
>
> ...
>
> ... The ideal humane interface would
>   reduce the interface component of a
>   user's work to **benign habituation**.
>   Many of the problems that make
>   products difficult and unpleasant to
>   use are caused by human-machine design
>   that fails to take into account the
>   helpful and injurious properties of
>   **habit formation**. One notable example
>   is the tendency to provide many ways
>   of accomplishing the same task. Having
>   multiple options can shift your locus
>   of attention from the task to the
>   choice of method...

But is contrary to what you describe in your question, as evidenced by the last 2 sentences. In fact in that book there is also a sub-chapter dedicated to dispel the myth of beginner-expert dichotomy:

> **3-6 Myth of the Beginner-Expert Dichotomy**
>
> ... This dichotomy is invalid. **As a user
>   of a complex system, you are neither
>   a beginner nor an expert, and you cannot
>   be placed on a single continuum between
>   these two poles**. You independently know
>   or do not know each feature or each related
>   set of features that work similarly to one
>   another. You may know how to use many
>   commands and features of a software package;
>   you may even work with the package professionally,
>   and people may seek your advice on using it.
>   Yet you may not know how to use or even know
>   about the existence of certain other commands
>   or even whole categories of commands in that
>   same package. ...

So, perhaps is not such a good term/concept that you are looking for.

**Update:** were you looking for the term [*Adaptive User Interfaces*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_user_interfaces), perhaps? Well, I think that, as usually understood and implemented, it is not such a great idea (for example, disappearing menu items in Microsoft products). But my impression is that researchers use the term for something quite different.

**Update:** but *Adaptive User Interfaces* does not cover scripting.

Comment: That term seems to contradict what I'm looking for. However, I'm eager to learn more about the concept in general, so if the term I'm looking for represents a bad practice, I want to know about that too. +1

Comment: Although I agree with the points Jef makes, I don't think they're at odds with what I'm looking for. What goes against his point about habituation exists in almost every application I've used, i.e. I can go to File->New or I can press Ctrl+N. Also I don't think the Beginner-Expert Dichotomy applies in this case because the concept is not an either-or condition, it's intended to cater to all users, for any feature or command. Interesting stuff though :)

Comment: In fact, he explicitly criticized existing applications and proposed to abandon the concept of application altogether.

Comment: Adaptive interfaces is not really what I'm thinking of, it's not that the application grows for the user, just that static functionality is always there, ready to be discovered when a user becomes more proficient - but nothing changes about the interface. Sorry I don't know how to explain it better - this kind of question must be quite infuriating :-|

Comment: Well, I'm not infuriated but really curious now.

Answer (score 3):

Accelerators?

> Flexibility and efficiency of use:
>   Accelerators -- unseen by the novice
>   user -- may often speed up the
>   interaction for the expert user such
>   that the system can cater to both
>   inexperienced and experienced users.
>   Allow users to tailor frequent
>   actions.

(source: [Ten Usability Heuristics by Jakob Nielsen](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html))

Comment: Ah, on second thoughts, this is similar to Tomislav's answer in that accelerators are specific to keyboard shortcuts and I'm looking for the abstract term prescribing the use of accelerators.

Comment: I believe the term "accelerators" is not specific to keyboard shortcuts -- for example, a quote from "Accommodating both Experts and Novices in One Interface" (http://otal.umd.edu/UUGuide/jingwu/) : "Typical accelerators include abbreviations, having function keys or command keys that package an entire command in a single keypress, double-clicking on an object to perform the most common operation on it,"

Comment: An accelerator on mobile, for example, would be the swipe gesture that lists commonly have to let users quickly delete list items. There are typically no visual affordances for those gestures to avoid cluttering up the UI.  Beginners tap on the item, go to the detail view, and might have a "delete" action there; experts swipe from the list screen.